# stuck in configuring mailman when install tuleap under ubuntu 12.10 64 bit server

Tags: alm, tuleap

I followed [this link](https://tuleap.net/plugins/forumml/message.php?group_id=101&topic=12118&list=1) to install tuleap in ubuntu 12.10 server 64 bit, but got stuck in the step "configure mailman".  It seems that the only choice is moving cursor to specific language then hit "enter", but it stuck in this step, can't move forward to next step, why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand what's your issue. If it's a question of "how to use" this interface, you're supposed to choose a language by highlighting it and then press «space» in order to select it. Then you can move to «ok» by pressing "enter" key.

In this case, choose English and go ahead!

-- Martin

Answer (score 0):

SPACEBAR - just select the language you need with the Spacebar and then use Tab to move the cursos to OK, then hit enter.